# wlp2s0 - failed to remove key on PC (can't stop laptop)

Tags: wireless, 17.10

I have this error when I decide to stop laptop MSI with Ubuntu 17.10 version.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2yKh.jpg)

[3050.207469] wlp2s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1720930 The bug is supposed to be fixed in a later kernel version.

Comment #17 and several comments following suggest that a change to GRUB will be a temporary work-around. I suggest that, from the terminal, you do:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To instead read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

Proofread carefully twice, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit the text editor (Ctrl+x).

Next, update GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and test.